# groovy: change each element of a list and join

Tags: collections, groovy, closures

I want to wrap each element of a list in single-quotes and join them into a string.

Sample input: `["aa", "bb", "cc"]`

Expected output: `"'aa', 'bb', 'cc'"`

I guessed that this could be done with a collect+closure, so I tried:

```
def mylist = ["aa", "bb", "cc"]
println mylist.collect{ 'it' }.join(', ')
```

But the output is: `"it, it, it"` and this is not what I want.

How can I append and pre-pend a single quote to each element of the list? Any other oneliner (or short) groovy solutions apart from collect and join?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should try

```
mylist.collect{ "'$it'" }.join(', ')
```

with `'it'` you just return the string "it".

Comment: it does not work...I tried mylist.collect{ "'$it.toUpperCase()'" }.join(', ')...not sure if that is due to toUpperCase method..

Comment: That's because you aren't calling the variable in the string the right way.  Try this: mylist.collect{ "'${it.toUpperCase()}'" }.join(', ')